# SQL Query to get the data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I am new to SQL development. So I would like to get some help from SO.

I have three tables : **student**, **student_addresses**, **student_phones**.

Their schema is roughly as follows :

```
student
-------
student_id (Primary Key)
student_name
father_name
mother_name

student_addresses
-----------------
student_address_id (Primary Key)
student_id (Foreign Key)
address
zip_code

student_phones
--------------
student_phone_id (Primary Key)
student_id (Foreign Key)
phone_type
phone_number
```

Both **student_addresses** and **student_phones** are a has_many relation. So I would like to SELECT all the fields from **student** for a particular **student_id** but only the matching counts(total) from student_addresses and **student_phones** for that **student_id**. How do I get that ?

I have tried this query, but it returns an error :

```
SELECT students.student_id,student_name,father_name,mother_name,
       COUNT(student_addresses.student_id) AS total_addresses,    
       COUNT(student_phones.student_id) AS total_phones
 FROM students,student_phones,student_addresses
 WHERE students.student_id = student_phones.student_id AND
       students.student_id = student_addresses.student_id AND
       students.student_id = 7;
```

PS : Currently I am using this on PostgreSQL. However, I would like to work it on MySQL also. So does that mean I need to have two different queries ? AFAIK, for this purpose, just a single query will work on both (since both MySQL and PostgreSQL follow the same SQL implementation, as far as this query requirement is concerned).

I am wondering, if I can do it without using GROUP BY. Because, suppose the student table has more fields, say 12, then I will have to put all of the field names both to SELECT as well as to GROUP BY(AFAIK), which seems a bit inelegant.

Comment: Do student_addresses and student_phones have their own primary keys? If so, what are they? Also, are you using PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Comment: @MarkBannister, I didn't notice that it has 2 different DB. I really thought that it's MySQL. Glad you point that out.

Comment: *"since both MySQL and PostgreSQL follow the same SQL implementation, as far as this query requirement is concerned"* - no, they don't. Specifically, you can get away with including unaggregated, ungrouped fields in grouped queries in MySQL, but you can't do so in PostgreSQL or any other implementation of SQL (that I am aware of) - this is almost certainly why you were getting the error you were getting.

Comment: @M-D: nevertheless, my query will both run on MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on MySQL and PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT s.student_id,
       max(s.student_name) student_name,
       max(s.father_name) father_name,
       max(s.mother_name) mother_name,
       COUNT(distinct a.student_address_id) total_addresses,    
       COUNT(distinct p.student_phone_id) total_phones
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN student_phones p ON s.student_id = p.student_id
LEFT JOIN student_addresses a ON s.student_id = a.student_id
WHERE s.student_id = 7
GROUP BY s.student_id
```

Comment: Why is the max() function required here ?

Comment: @M-D: Because this is a grouped query - all columns in the select statement have to be either included in the grouping criteria, or aggregated. I prefer to use an aggregation function (such as `max`) because on fields that aren't **required** for the grouping, because it is clearer what the "real" grouping is.

Comment: @M-D, I think you are after the 'elegance' of the code. I understand and it's good but not also **required**. :)

Comment: @Christian Mark: Yes, I like efficient,simple and elegant (In that order actually). Lengthy codes make our life harder in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT students.student_id,student_name,father_name,mother_name,
       COUNT(student_addresses.student_id) AS total_addresses,    
       COUNT(student_phones.student_id) AS total_phones
 FROM students,student_phones,student_addresses
 WHERE students.student_id = student_phones.student_id AND
       students.student_id = student_addresses.student_id AND
       students.student_id = 7
 GROUP BY students.student_id,student_name,father_name,mother_name;
```

But if it happens that student with id 7 has no address or no phone number, it will return no result. To return something even in this case, try using `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT students.student_id,student_name,father_name,mother_name,
       COUNT(student_addresses.student_id) AS total_addresses,    
       COUNT(student_phones.student_id) AS total_phones
 FROM students
 LEFT JOIN student_phones ON students.student_id = student_phones.student_id
 LEFT JOIN student_addresses ON students.student_id = student_addresses.student_id
 WHERE students.student_id = 7
 GROUP BY students.student_id,student_name,father_name,mother_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT students.student_id,student_name,father_name,mother_name,
           COUNT(student_addresses.student_id) AS total_addresses,    
           COUNT(student_phones.student_id) AS total_phones
     FROM students,student_phones,student_addresses
     WHERE students.student_id = student_phones.student_id AND
           students.student_id = student_addresses.student_id AND
           students.student_id = 7
    GROUP BY BY students.student_id,student_name,father_name,mother_name;
```

Comment: I am wondering, if I can do it without using GROUP BY. Because, suppose the student table has more fields, say 12, then I will have to put all of the field names both to SELECT as well as to GROUP BY, which seems a bit inelegant. Am I not correct ?

Comment: It is possible to just create a `VIEW` and form another query with `INNER JOIN` but why bother if you can do it in one query?